# How does it work QasmSimulator with the option "density matrix"?

Tags: qiskit, programming, noise, ibm-quantum-devices, qasm

I am making some simulations on IBM Quantum Lab and as backend I tried to use QasmSimulator(method = "density_matrix") in order to simulate noise. I wanted to know how this method works in detail, because on the Qiskit Documentation I didn't find the details.